# Lucene Fuzzy Match on Phrase instead of Single Word

Tags: lucene, solr, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to do a fuzzy match on the Phrase "Grand Prarie" (deliberately misspelled) using Apache Lucene. Part of my issue is that the `~` operator only does fuzzy matches on single word terms and behaves as a proximity match for phrases.

Is there a way to do a fuzzy match on a phrase with lucene?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lucene 3.0 has [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/contrib-misc/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html) that supports fuzzy phrase query. This is in the contrib package.

Answer (score 4):

Came across this through Google and felt solutions where not what I was after.
In my case, solution was to simply repeat the search sequence against the solr API.
So for example if I was looking for: title_t to include match for "dog~" and "cat~", I added some manual code to generate query as:

```
((title_t:dog~) and (title_t:cat~))
```

It might just be what above queries are about, however links seems dead.

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct support for a fuzzy phrase, but you can simulate it by explicitly [enumerating the fuzzy terms](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyTermEnum.html) and then adding them to a [MultiPhraseQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiPhraseQuery.html).  The resulting query would look like:

```
<MultiPhraseQuery: "grand (prarie prairie)">
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this? I'm not using Lucene directly, but rather through Solr. 

I may very well have to just get around to reading lucene in action. I wouldn't mind getting a better understanding of how the two work together and becoming comfortable with it at a more fundamental level.

For now, in Solr, I'm achieving something that's effective enough for me using the solr.PhoneticFilterFactory analyzer.